# GlassFish can't connect to mysql (XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, glassfish, xampp

I'm trying to connect my glassfish with a mysql server (installed via XAMPP) and it says:

Ping Connection Pool failed for jdbc/xxxx. Connection could not be allocated because: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Please check the server.log for more details.

My configs in glassfish are:
URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SIRS
User: root
Password: xxxxxxx

Both servers are in the same pc running ubuntu.

I have the same configurations working properly in another pc but without XAMPP installation, I've installed mysql server with apt-get install mysql... command.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks.

JB

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that mysql server & glassfish server are installed on the same host.
So, you should go to etc/mysql/my.cnf if there is a public ip address bind you should remove it and put only bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Another case is that in stead of URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SIRS you should put 
URL: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/SIRS
This worked for me.